# How to remove ajax image upload notice

Tags: php, ajax, image-uploading

I am doing project in php.I used ajax code to  upload the image.
It done nicely, everything is working but display notice and i want 2 remove this notice...
Notice is as follows:

- **Notice: Undefined variable: errorList in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\scripts\ajaxupload.php on line 18 Notice:
  Undefined variable: errorList in
  C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\scripts\ajaxupload.php on line 132**

i am not understanding  what is the meaning of message...
How to remove this Notice?

Comment: My bet: your variable errorList in ajaxupload.php isn't defined. Two options. a) Define it before using it (good), b) surpress the notice (bad).

Comment: not easy to describe without the code. before the variable is used, put a `var $errorList;`, this declares/defines the variable.

Comment: @Bjoern `var` is such an oldschool. :)

Comment: if i am declaring var $errorList;   
it show
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\scripts\ajaxupload.php on line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the notice you must either check is this variable `$errorList` defined and if it is, then check `ajaxupload.php on line 18` and `ajaxupload.php on line 132` does it see it there or is it out of the scope.

The other thing you could do is place at the beginning of PHP file `ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`, but this really bad idea since `Notice` is made to show what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the variables as null before using them, so that by default they will be null until given a value from elsewhere.  Variables defined inside an if block or by user input sometimes don't get defined, right? So for them, a default is needed sso that they at least exist even if they aren't given a value.

```
$errorList = null;
```